# Was it a Bird I Heard?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

I was taking a walk, trying hard to unwind
but was suddenly startled by a swoosh! from behind
This sound was soon followed by an "eek!" overhead
but before I could see what it was, it had fled.
I didn't feel relaxed as I yelled "argh!" out loud
and everyone heard me, I didn't feel so proud
I scare very easily, it's somewhat of a niggle,
it caused quite a few folk around me to giggle
"Ugh!" I said, I don't know why I'm so prickly
Lub-dub! Lub-dub! My heart still beating so quickly
I continued my walk, feeling shaken and stirred
and I'm still not sure what it was I might have heard!

**What did I hear?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You heard a

> seagull

because

> if you take the first letter of every sound you heard, in the order you heard them, you get seagull. 
>  
>  The sounds were: 
>  
>  **S**woosh 
>  **E**ek 
>  **A**rgh 
>  **G**iggle 
>  **U**gh 
>  **L**ub-dub, **L**ub-dub 
>  
>  So it **was** a bird you heard!

Comment: Nice acrostics :)

Comment: Nice one. A perfect answer, although I was hoping that someone would also spot that ROT13(Gur jbeqf qba'g whfg qrfpevor fbhaqf, gurl ner babzngbcbrvp!)